# HP DL380 G7 RAID controller detecting bays incorrectly - port or mobo?

Tags: raid, hp, controller

I've been passed a DL380 G7 which appears to work fine (all usual checks come back OK, Linux boots OK, LV creation is OK and disk access is OK) -- except the left hand four bays connected to port 1 of the controller don't report correct IDs.

There's six drives in bays 1-3 and 5-7. A riser card is fitted for a third box but nothing's currently attached. The controller on the board is a P410. Both bays have three 146 GB SAS cards apiece (left three are 15k, right three are 10k - a quirk of the config). When I powered up the server, it already had a RAID 5 configured, displayed as "OK" and was visible as available unformatted space in a Parted Magic LiveCD.

The BIOS, controller utility and accompanying CLI utility all enumerate the left box as 5, 6, 7 and 8 on port 1i (the right hand box enumerates as expected on port 2i as 5, 6, 7 and 8). A symptom of this is that the front panel UID and activity LEDs don't light up on the left bay -- swapping the cables on the mobo result in the left bay's LEDs working and the right bay's not, so something's very wrong here. Using the CLI to flash the LEDs made no difference, only the LEDs for drives going through the second port blinked. All drives are fully visible and status reports back as expected.

Might it be the interface card just behind the bays that's borked, or is it a mobo problem? I've never come across this before and I've not found much by way of similar issues discussed online.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, I ended up having HP support send an engineer to replace the mainboard. Fortunately the server was still within initial warranty. Based on analysis and logs I provided, they determined the RAID controller was partly faulty - an engineer duly arrived and replaced the mainboard. Problem solved. Nothing I could have done would have fixed this particular issue!